# Error in removing a css class from code behind in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two buttons on my asp.net content page of a master page. Next and Previous. By default Previous button is disabled but when user clicks on the Next button the previous button is enabled. I have applied a **disabled** style to the Previous button on load and want to remove this style on the Next button click. I m trying something like this but getting the error below on  this line

> btnPrevious.Attributes["CssClass"].Replace("disabled", "");

```
 protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
         btnPrevious.Enabled = true;
         btnPrevious.Attributes["CssClass"].Replace("disabled", "");
         //bla bla bla
         }
     }
```

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any ideas?

Button mark up

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnPrevious" runat="server"   OnClick="btnPrevious_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary disabled" Enabled="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> Back</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: could you please show us your design file aswell, it seems there is no `CSSClass` Attribue for `btnPrevious`

Comment: You better use **CssClass** property of the object. Or a client side solution with JS.